# Can I create an event grid subscription to an Azure function app before the function is published?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-function-app

I have been trying to create an event grid subscription to an Event Grid Trigger function which is created to capture Blob storage events, using ARM templates. I successfully create the function app resource first, then try to create the event grid subscription on the created function app, but it fails with the following error:

```
    "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Url validation",
        "message": "The attempt to validate the provided endpoint https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation."
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here I have used webhook URL as the endpoint. I've come to know that there is a validation call that goes back to the function app to verify its existence.

My question is, do we need to publish the Event Grid Trigger function to the function app **before** trying to create an event grid subscription for that?

P.S. I have also tried the same order with AzureFunction as the endpoint type ([2020-01-01 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/2020-01-01-preview/eventsubscriptions#EventSubscriptionDestination)), but it still failed to create the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the validation details described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#validation-details):

```
At the time of event subscription creation/update, Event Grid posts a subscription validation event to the target endpoint
```

as a workaround, you can use a dummy (nop operation) subscriber handler endpoint for creating your subscription and then update a webhook endpoint with your real subscriber handler endpoint.

Comment: Hi @RomanKiss , thank you for your answer. Is there any way I can do the suggested dummy op with an AzureFunction endpoint rather than with a WebHook?

Comment: you can create (manualy via a portal) an *EventGridTrigger* function for this dummy (nop-operation) subscriber handler and use it for your needs.

Comment: Thank you @RomanKiss, I managed to place another deployment task before creating the event subscription, to allow some time for the event trigger function to be deployed properly, and it worked.